# Return Applescript Shell Output to Objective C

Tags: objective-c, bash, shell, applescript

I am writing a application that can run shell commands remotely. I need to run the command:        `tc -l 455` as an administrator. I decided to run this command in applescript with administrative privileges but in objective c I need to take this output and display it in a NSTexView. Here is my code:

```
NSAppleScript* runWithAdminPrivileges = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:@"do     shell script \"nc -l 455\" with administrator privileges"];
NSDictionary *error = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
[runWithAdminPrivileges executeAndReturnError:&error];
NSLog(@"%@", error);
```

The command is running but I have no way of seeing the output. Is there a way to do this with my code or is there a way to run this shell command in objective c with admin privileges and view the output?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: You can use `NSTask`: [How to use NSTask as root?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4050687)

Comment: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_STPrivilegedTask", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: This is the error I get when I run STPrivilegedTask

Comment: STPrivilegedTask isn't built in to Cocoa. You need to download the files and compile them.

Comment: I did download them and imported them into my project. In the source code there are no errors. It is only this runtime error.

Comment: That's a linker error. Make sure STPrivilegedTask.m is correctly added to your build. It needs to be marked as a member of your target in the File Inspector, and be listed in the "Compile Sources" Build Phase.

Comment: I added it to those places and now it gives me all these reference counting errors. Is there any way I can have automatic reference counting for everything but stprivilegedtask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-[NSAppleScript executeAndReturnError:]` returns a result you’re ignoring, which is the result of the script.  It’s an NSAppleEventDescriptor, not an NSString, but you can get an NSString by calling `-stringValue` on it.  Also, the `error` parameter follows the same rules as `NSError **` parameters elsewhere, so you don’t need to fill it in with an object first.  To sum up:

```
NSDictionary *errorInfo; // no initialization necessary.
NSAppleEventDescriptor *scriptResult = [runWithAdminPrivileges executeAndReturnError:&error];
if (scriptResult)
    NSLog(@“%@“, [scriptResult stringValue]);
else
    NSLog(@“%@“, errorInfo;
```