# How to obtain Bluetooth MAC Address using Swift on OSX

Tags: swift, macos, bluetooth

I've looked online in many places on trying to obtain the Bluetooth MAC Address of my Macbook Air. Everything I've stumbled upon has only been based towards iOS development and nothing towards the macOS field. Everything else says it has been depreciated past iOS 7, so I don't know if it would be possible on the latest Mac operating system. Does anyone know if it is possible under any framework? I'm not looking to submit this to the App Store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Using a Bash Script

I'd like to thank @MattGalaxy for the suggestion and the assistance shown in the comments below under his answer. Eventually, it all worked out well and here's how I pulled this off. This can work in a Playground or in a macOS application you are building with Xcode.

Here's the code to go along with it:

```
 import Foundation
 let task = Process()
 task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/env"
 task.arguments = ["networksetup", "-getmacaddress", "en2"]
 let pipe = Pipe()
 task.standardOutput = pipe
 task.standardError = pipe
 task.launch()
 task.waitUntilExit()
 let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
 let output: String = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) as! String
```

The original was this:

```
Ethernet Address: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX (Device: en2)
```

This does say Ethernet address, **however**, the device `en2` is specifically used for Bluetooth, so all this captures is that.

I set the variable `bluetoothAddress` equal to the output above.

```
var bluetoothAddress = output
```

And then just played around until I was able to crunch only the address between these.

```
let startIndex = bluetoothAddress.index(bluetoothAddress.startIndex, offsetBy: 18)
let endIndex = bluetoothAddress.index(bluetoothAddress.startIndex, offsetBy: 34)
bluetoothAddress = bluetoothAddress[startIndex...endIndex]
```

And then finally, giving off the output I was requesting for originally in the question:

```
XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
```

(Keep in mind, I used placeholder XX's throughout this answer to keep my privacy :P)

Answer (score 0):

The best option I could find for obtaining the Bluetooth MAC Address from a macOS app with Swift revolves around [executing a terminal command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31193037/6836841) and then formatting the output.

It would just be a matter of specifying the `launchPath` of `networksetup` 
& using the flag `listallhardwareports` to obtain an [output](http://osxdaily.com/2012/02/28/find-mac-address-mac-os-x/).

Comment: I've reconsidered using this information as of now, but this does seem the most logical when trying to obtain the address. Thanks anyways!

Comment: @dylan - No problem, sorry I couldn't be of more help.  I was originally going to suggest importing `C` code into `Swift` to use [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/samplecode/GetPrimaryMACAddress/Introduction/Intro.html) - but obviously that's not the MAC address you're looking for.  Doesn't seem they have a Bluetooth version implemented yet.

Comment: I was able to get the output, as follows: `Ethernet Address: 00:00:00:00:00:00 (Hardware Port: Bluetooth PAN)`. How can I only subject my output to the address rather than the information with the hardware port and stating "Ethernet Address:" beforehand. Thanks! @MattGalaxy

Comment: If encasing the `shell` function call with `readLine` doesn't allow you to capture the output from the command- I'd suggest trying implement a [pipe](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/pipe) (perhaps using the code I linked to in my answer as an example?) Glad I can help though :)

Comment: I actually changed mine over to yours in this time, I'm just trying to figure out how to remove the beginning. I can remove the end characters, just nothing before the address. @MattGalaxy

Comment: If you're using `substring`, you should be specifying a `range` where the start index is where the first 0 is & the end index is whatever offset you've used to cut the end off

Comment: My mind is in a bit of a wrap about this, if I saw how it was wrote out I would probably understand what makes it work, lol. @MattGalaxy

Comment: Sorry! On mobile, but I should've linked an answer like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33733593/6836841).

Comment: `startIndex` should be offset to the first 0, & `endIndex` would be that plus the length of a MAC (11)

Comment: My start ended up as 18 and end was 34. But I still managed to get the output I liked, thanks!

Comment: Okay, last question while I'm here. I defined it as a function with the variables inside, if I need to access them anywhere else in the file do I need to store them outside of the function? Thanks. @MattGalaxy

Comment: Test it out! But you're correct. Variables only exist within the scope they're declared in with Swift.

Comment: Would you mind if I provide the answer in full and accept that one instead? @MattGalaxy

Comment: I mentioned you in the answer. @MattGalaxy